# FindByIdAndUpdate is updating but returning null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

This is the first time I come here for some guidance, but I dont know what else to try.

I have a household collection that contains a member collection in it. When new members sign in, I need to be able to update the household collection with the new members.

This is what my household controler looks like:

```
update: function(req, res) {
  db.Household
    .findByIdAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.params.id},
      {$push: {members: req.body.id}},
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false})
    .then(dbModel => { return res.json(dbModel); })
    .catch(console.log)
  ;
}
```

On the frontend I just hardcoded the new member id from our seed, since I am waiting to finish up passport authentication and incorporate it to this). I looks like this:

```
const memberData = '5ecdc629e77964b5b474c19f'
```

I would appreciate if someone could let me know why is it being added as a member with the update but saved as null.

Thank you!

Comment: In your frontend what are you sending in you request `body`?

Answer (score 0):

```
update: function(req, res) {
  db.Household
    .findByIdAndUpdate(
      {req.params.id},
      {"members": req.body.id},
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false})
    .then(dbModel => { return res.json(dbModel); })
    .catch(console.log)
  ;
}
```

try this